# How do you add d3-selection-multi to d3?

Tags: angular, d3.js

I love d3 V4's ability to make me feel completely incompetent. I can't seem to figure out how to make my own custom bundle in webpack along with my other modules... so instead I'm simply trying to take the vanilla d3 bundle and add multi-selection capability to it.

I created a d3 service in Angular 2, to dependency inject the d3 object between my components.

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";

import * as d3 from "d3";
import "d3-selection-multi";
export type D3 = typeof d3;

@Injectable()
export class D3Service {
    constructor() {
    }

    private d3: D3 = d3;

    getD3 = () => {
        return this.d3;
    };
}
```

Everything works great, until I try to access the multiple selection capabilities, like using .attrs

```
let test = this.d3.select("body").styles({
            "background-color": "#F00",
            "color": "#00F"
        });
```

My browser complains that it doesn't know what .attrs is.

> error_handler.js:47 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in
>   ./ListingComponent class ListingComponent_Host - inline template:0:0
>   caused by: this.d3.select(...).styles is not a function TypeError:
>   this.d3.select(...).styles is not a function

I've also tried merging the two ojects with `Object.assign` to no avail.

What am I doing wrong? It's probably something stupidly trivial.

Comment: Hit the very same issue with attrs()... didn't solve.

Comment: same here. I opened a github issue for it https://github.com/d3/d3-selection-multi/issues/19

Answer (score -2):

There is not a function named d3.styles.Please try this.

```
this.d3.select("body").style("background-color", "#F00")
                      .style("color", "#00F");
```

Comment: There is `styles` in d3 selection-multi. OP's question is exactly about it.